# can not check whether a temp table exists or not in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a temp table and I am writing a trigger if table exists then it will copy data from that table.

my code looks something like this:

```
BEGIN

If(client UTC=NULL AND temp_tab NOT EXISTS)

THEN SET NEW.client UTC=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

END IF;

END
```

This above code showing syntax error. Please suggest me how can I fix this problem and how can I check if a table exists or not.

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question

Comment: You can check existence of table by SELECTing from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: My error message saying that you have a syntax error near 'not exists'.